# XPAGES : take the answer of user by the dropdownbutton

Tags: java, xpages, lotus-domino, xpages-ssjs

I try to recover the answer of the user but i can't.
I have a dropdownbutton, I recover the list and the value by default by a java class.
It's ok about this.
But when I try to push another text of the list : nothing append...

```
<xe:dropDownButton id="dropdownEtatDoc">
            <xe:this.treeNodes>
                <xe:basicContainerNode>
                    <!--            Affiche l'état du document par défaut-->
                    <xe:this.label id="labelEtatDoc">
                        <![CDATA[#{javascript:                      
                            etatDoc.nomEtatDoc;                     
                        }]]>
                    </xe:this.label>
                    <!--            affiche la liste des états du document-->
                    <xe:repeatTreeNode var="index"  value="#{etatDoc.listEtatDoc}">
                        <xe:this.children>
                            <xe:basicLeafNode label="#{index}" submitValue="#{index}" />
                        </xe:this.children>
                    </xe:repeatTreeNode>
                </xe:basicContainerNode>
            </xe:this.treeNodes>
                    <!--            actualise la chaine sélectionnée-->
                    <xp:eventHandler event="onItemClick" submit="true"
                        refreshMode="complete">
                        <xp:this.action>
                            <xp:executeScript>
                                <xp:this.script><![CDATA[#{javascript:                      
                                var montest = getComponent("dropdownEtatDoc").submittedValue();
                                etatDoc.nomEtatDoc = montest;
                        }]]></xp:this.script>
                            </xp:executeScript>
                        </xp:this.action>
                    </xp:eventHandler>
        </xe:dropDownButton>
```

An idea ? Thanks !

I use a combobox and it's ok, I don't know why...

My code for anyone has the same problem :

```
<xp:this.beforePageLoad>
        <xp:executeScript>
            <xp:this.script><![CDATA[#{javascript:
            viewScope.etat = etatDoc.listEtatDoc;
            viewScope.grdFam = chapitre.listChapitre1;          
            }]]></xp:this.script>           
        </xp:executeScript>
    </xp:this.beforePageLoad>   

    <xp:div>
        <!--**************** DEBUT CBXETATDOC *************************************************************-->              
                <xp:label value="Etat : " id="label1"></xp:label>
                <xp:comboBox id="cbxEtat">                                  
                    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Tout" itemValue="" />
                    <xp:selectItems value="#{viewScope.etat}" />
                    <xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="true" refreshMode="complete" immediate="true">
                        <xp:this.action>
                            <xp:executeScript>
                                <xp:this.script>
                                    <![CDATA[#{javascript:
                                        var etat = getComponent("cbxEtat").submittedValue;                                                      
                                    }]]>
                                </xp:this.script>
                            </xp:executeScript>
                        </xp:this.action>
                    </xp:eventHandler>
                </xp:comboBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "etatDoc" is a NotesXspDocument and not a bean.

1) If you are having trouble getting the submitted value, get it via the context:

```
var submitted = context.getSubmittedValue();
print("submitted: " + submitted);  //check if it is there, delete afterward
switch(submitted){
case("btn1")
//doSomething(submitted);
break;

}
```

Since you are using the repeater node, it would not be practical to use the switch for all of it, but you could make a default where you do what ever you need to with the index value.

2) then I do not think you are setting the value properly.  Try:

```
var montest = submitted;
etatDoc.replaceItemValue("nomEtatDoc", etatDoc.getItemValue("nomEtatDoc").add(montest))
//gets the current list (java.util.Vector) from the document
//add a value to the list
//replace the value with the new list
```

I am assuming that you are not using a self-made-bean for this.